# What is _wsystem equivalent in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

What are equivalents for [_tsystem and _wsystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx)   in linux?‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `system`. There are no wide-string (Unicode) APIs in Linux.

Comment: so how to add a unicode argument? terminal window accepts!

Comment: You can use utf8 encoding

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: the short version of the long answer is: strings like paths are just bytes in POSIX APIs. So the `char *` string you pass to a function may actually contain utf16 data, if that's what's stored on disk (although I've never seen anyone use that - utf8 is much more common).

Comment: give the command to system in utf8 format, since linux file systems are encoded in utf8. that's why you don't need to use unicode. for plain ASCII characters there is no difference.

Comment: @Minimus You can convert it with `wcstombs`.

Comment: "linux file system is encoded in utf8" --- incorrect. File names are strings of bytes. You interpret them in any encoding you wish. Linux does not impose any interpretation.

Comment: @n.m. I meant string of bytes with terminating null at the end = (utf8) and not wide bytes (unicode). you can't give unicode to system command because usually there is a 0 every 2nd byte...

Comment: @vanza It would be rather difficult to interpret filenames as UTF16 data, given that they cannot contain zero bytes, and ASCII `/` byte is the path separator.

Comment: @SHR "string of bytes with terminating null at the end" and "utf8" are very far from being the same thing.  "Unicode" is not parallel to "utf8", they are of different categories. One is an encoding and the other is a character set (and an international standard). UTF-8 is one possible encoding of unicode characters, UTF-16 is another one. UTF-32 is another one. All of these things are unicode.

Comment: @n.m. yeah, utf16 might have been a bad example, but replace it with "shift-jis" or any other null-terminated multi-byte encoding and the idea is the same.